# Copying file from raw to external storage

Tags: android, android-file, android-external-storage

Trying to copy a PDF file (template) to a custom directory in the external storage (non-sd card).

```
public void copyPDFToExternal(String newFileName) throws IOException {
        // Create directory folder if it doesnt exist.
        File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +
                File.separator + "pdfFolder");
        if (!folder.exists()){
            folder.mkdir();
        }

        // Copy template
        InputStream in = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.pdf_template);
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +
            File.separator + "pdfFolder/"+newFileName+".pdf");

        byte[] buff = new byte[1024];
        int read = 0;
        try {
            while ((read = in.read(buff)) > 0 ) {
                out.write(buff, 0, read);
            }
        } finally {
            in.close();
            out.close();
        }

    }
```

I have added the following to AndroidManifest.xml, not in the application tag.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Full error: http://pastebin.com/TBtbekiB

If you need me to post anything else let me know.

Where have I gone wrong?

Update: No longer crashes but now doesn't seem to do anything... the mkdirs returns true.

```
public void copyPDFToExternal(String newFileName) throws IOException {
        File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() +
                "/test/");
        if (!folder.exists()){
            if (!folder.mkdirs()){
                eme.setText("Failed");
                return;
            };
        }

        InputStream in = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.ohat);
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(folder.getAbsolutePath() +"/"+newFileName+".pdf");

        byte[] buff = new byte[1024];
        int read = 0;
        try {
            while ((read = in.read(buff)) > 0 ) {
                out.write(buff, 0, read);
            }
        } finally {
            in.close();
            out.close();
        }
    }
```

I've also added a permission request, this is a little long so using pastebin.

http://pastebin.com/KgivWNuc

Edit 2:

So it seems it does work, just the directory cannot be see when the device is connected to a computer (in MTP mode). But I guess that's another issue.

Comment: Try using Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();

If you are specifying folders then first run mkdirs() on the file reference first.

Comment: Same issue. Throws java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/pdfFolder/testfile.pdf: I run folder.mkdir() if folder.exists() returns false, is that the wrong way to do it?

Comment: it's alright that way, mkdirs just creates all of the folders in between, try creating a file reference with only the path and not the pdf name, and then create it.

Comment: Sorry, still new to android, what do you mean?

Comment: new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/test/"); something like this.

Comment: Same issue.

File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() +
                "/test/");
        folder.mkdirs();

Comment: `folder.mkdir();` Check the return value as it might fail. `if(!folder.mkdirs()){ toast could not make dir; return;}`.

Comment: also, what version of Android are you using?

Comment: `FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +
            File.separator + "pdfFolder/"+newFileName+".pdf");`. That is not an error but bad coding practice as you should not twice call get external storage directory() and set up the path again but use the first `folder` instance instead. `FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(folder.getAbsolutePath() +"/"+newFileName+".pdf");`.

Comment: Running android 6.0

Answer (score 0):

if you are installing in device os version android M and more you need to take permission at runtime. Adding in manifest alone is not sufficient. Refer [this](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) for more details.

Comment: I've added a method to request permissions, seen here: http://pastebin.com/KgivWNuc

While it no longer crashes, it wont create the directory.

Answer (score 0):

Can you specify which external storage you are using as you have said it is (non SD Card) because if you are using `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` then it will give you the path of SD Card Storage, something like this `/storage/emulated/0/` where 0 represents primary storage device.

Comment: No that will NOT give the path to a removable SD card.

Comment: From what I've read external storage is the folders outside of your apps data folder.

Basically I want to create the folder in the same directory as the public folders (music, pictures, etc).